# Can't Block https://facebook using squid Transparent

Tags: https, squid

I'm using Squid Proxy 3.1 as transparent proxy server, I want to block facebook.com but while listed in blocked list , Some user's accessing facebook using https, how can i block only https for facebook

Comment: You need to block all the IP addresses it maps to. With `https`, you don't get to see the name of the server they're trying to reach, only the IP address.

Comment: I Have used every IP's Of facebook too
Here are the list 

.facebook.com
66.220.144.0/20
66.220.144.0/21
66.220.152.0/21
66.220.159.0/24
69.63.176.0/20
69.63.176.0/21
69.63.176.0/24
69.63.184.0/21
69.171.224.0/19
69.171.224.0/20
69.171.239.0/24
69.171.240.0/20
69.171.255.0/24
74.119.76.0/22
103.4.96.0/22
173.252.64.0/18
173.252.64.0/19
173.252.70.0/24
173.252.96.0/19
204.15.20.0/22
31.13.24.0/21
31.13.64.0/18
31.13.64.0/19
31.13.64.0/24
31.13.65.0/24
31.13.66.0/24
31.13.67.0/24
31.13.68.0/24
31.13.69.0/24
31.13.70.0/24
31.13.71.0/24
31.13.72.0/24
31.13.73.0/24

Comment: Why does it need to be a transparent proxy?  As a configured proxy, you'll be able to actually work with the HTTPS requests sent by clients.

Comment: If i mentioned the proxy settings in Browser user's used to change it, so what i need to use it, And my squid Server have 2 Ethernet to route

Comment: `If i mentioned the proxy settings in Browser user's used to change it` - Update your firewall so if they do change it they won't be able to access the Internet.  That means block all outgoing traffic that doesn't pass through the proxy.  You can make exceptions for a few sites you explicitly whitelist.

Comment: ok let me try and ill be back , thanks for spending your precious times

Comment: If you wanna block something on HTTPS protocol you'll need to know what's on the SSL tunnel, so either you have a PaloAlto style appliance / Squid module able to handle SSL Traffic OR ultimatly you could be able to trick your users since if you're on Corporate environnement you're able to control DNS which (at least most of time) are not using SSL.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get the most up-to-date list of Facebook IP addresses using the folowing query

```
 whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'
```

The current list is somewhat longer than the one in your comment above. It should be fairly easy to parse the output of that query and load it into your firewall.

---

Answer (score 0):

And if you decide to go explicit proxy way, be sure to setup ICAP web filtering with Squid and (possibly) HTTPS/SSL bumping. In this case SquidGuard will be able to filter actual HTTPS urls. If it is not possible to perform HTTPS filtering - use qlproxy to block access to CONNECT:443 request for facebook.com domain name only as you require.

Comment: Can i use it in same squid transparent ? what i'm using now ?

Comment: Probably something like http://6pmsolutions.com/2013/11/18/squid-transparent-ssl-interception/

Comment: ok let me have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this in squid.conf:

```
acl blockfb dstdomain -i ".facebook.com"
http_access deny blockfb
```

Since the initial CONNECT request still comes through as HTTP, it should be able to catch it and block it.